# migrating from PostgreSQL 14 to PostgreSQL 15

Tags: postgresql-15

is it possible to restore the backup taken from PostgreSQL 14 to 15, I am taking backup using `pg_basebackup`

We are also migrating from centos to ubuntu.

Please advice, thank you

Comment: https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/upgrading-and-updating-postgresql/